# Python. Não consigo retornar um if statement dentro de uma função

Tags: python

```
def func(x=1, y=3):

  if x == y:
  return "Igualdade."
  else: 
    return "Desigualdade."
  if x > y or x < y:
    return True
  if True == x > y:
    return x
  else:
    return y
if x < y:
  return (y - x) == c
  if c + x == y:
      return "Agora está igual!"
  else:
    return "Afinal, não está igual."
```

Já está resolvido. Obrigado a todos pela ajuda, aqui vai como ficou o código.
Nota: tirei- o da função.

```
x = 1
y = 3

if x == y:
  print("Igualdade.")
else: 
  print("Desigualdade.") 
if x > y or x < y:
  print(True)
if True == x > y:
  print("x", x)
else:
  print("y", y)
if x < y:
 print(y - x) 
if y - x + x == y:
  x = y - x + x
if x == y:
  print("Agora está igual!")
```

Mexi mais um bocado e agora adicionando 'else', 'and' e 'not'.

```
if x == y:
  print("Igualdade.")
else: 
  print("Desigualdade.") 
if x > y and not x < y:
  print("x", x)
else:
  print("y", y)
if x < y:
  print(y - x) 
if y - x + x == y:
  x = y - x + x
if x == y:
  print("Agora está igual!")
```

Outra opção.

```
if x == y:
  print("Igualdade.")
else: 
  print("Desigualdade.") 
if x > y and not x < y:
  print("x", x)
else:
  print("y", y)
if x > y:
  y = (x - y) + y
else:
  x = (y - x) + x 
if x == y:
  print("Agora está igual!")
```

Comment: Poderia explicar o que está tentando fazer?

Comment: Olá, amigo, eu estava querendo retornar a menssagem, no fim do código. Onde diz, "Afinal, não está igual". Mas eu já consegui. Ao invés de explicar, vou postar o código aqui para vc ver como ficou.

Comment: x = 1
    y = 3

    if x == y:
      print("Igualdade.")
    else: 
      print("Desigualdade.") 
    if x > y or x < y:
      print(True)
    if True == x > y:
      print("x", x)
    else:
      print("y", y)
    if x < y:
      print(y - x) 
    if y - x + x == y:
      x = y - x + x
    if x == y:
      print("Agora está igual!")

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado.

Comment: Obrigado. Abraço amigo.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo seu código só as primeiras 4 linhas da função estão fazendo algo. O comando `Return` sai da função e o primeiro if está falando sair da função com o valor de igualdade se x for igual a y, ou sair da função com desigualdade se x não for igual a y, o resto da função não é executada nunca.

Comment: Olá, pois é, reparei no erro. Apesar de ter corrigido antes de ver seu comentário, obrigado, ainda sim me ajudou. Abraço amigo.